# Why isn't it printing the value of the key but instead searches for a variable with a name of the value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, format, eval

[image: example]

I've tried so many variations. Too many to list, and have scoured the internet for answers, but I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: because you are using an f-string. Why are you using an f-string? That makes you **interpolate** whatever is inside the `{}` brackets, in this case, the string is `print(bruh)` which gets evaluated, but there is no name `bruh` defined. I think you just want `print(d["A"])`, no `eval`, not f-string

Comment: and stop using `eval`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

you use an `f String`. Thus, `{d["A"]}` is evaluated **before** putting the string into eval resulting into `eval("print(bruh)")`.
Try this:

```py
d = {"A": "bruh"}
eval('print(d["A"])')
```